# Form validation on Facebook tab

Tags: validation, firebug, fbml, fbjs

I am using static FBML but I am having trouble debugging a form validation problem. I get the dialog which to me seems like it should return false, but the form submits anyway. I am using Firebug and I see a brief message in Red that I have no chance to read. I appreciate the help :-)

```
var txt ='Enter Zipcode';
//...
function  setError(){
 var obj=document.getElementById('mapsearch');
        obj.setValue(txt);
        obj.setStyle('color', '#FF0000'); 
}
function valform(){
 var obj=document.getElementById('mapsearch');
 var val = obj.getValue();
 if(val!='' &&  !isNaN(val) && val.length>2 ){ 
  return true;
 } else {
  setError();
  (new Dialog()).showMessage('Zip Required', 'Please enter your zip code.');
  return false;
 }
}





 
 
    
//...
```

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint in valform() to see if return false is executed?

Comment: Facebook generates some pretty screwy URLs. It was simple really, I just changed the method to post and that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the "Persist" button if the Firebug/javascript error message in Firebug disappears too quickly. This way all messages are kept between page loads until you click "Clear".